# Trying to calculate the value of a transform

Tags: javascript, function, css-transforms

I'm trying to make a function to calculate the value that I need to make the svg moving from a Point A to a Point B with an angle.
On this image, I have a flower
[image]
I would like to do that :
[image: The result]
I'm trying to make a function to calculate the translateX, translateY and the degree of the rotation but that doesn't work and I don't know how to fix it, here's my code :

```
var texte = document.getElementsByClassName("texte");
//Here, the coordinates where I want each petal to arrive, I will try to make something to calculate it depending on the screen...
var arriveex = 1082.4940185546875;
var arriveey = 8.80517578125;
var arriveeright = 1402.2513427734375;
var arriveewidth = 319.75732421875;
var arriveeheight = 256.9661865234375;

//The function to calculate the distance between the starting point and the finishing point
function getDistanceX(x1, x2){
  let x = x2 - x1;
  return Math.sqrt(x*x);}

function getDistanceY(y1, y2) {
    let y = y2 - y1;
    return Math.sqrt(y*y);
}
                                                  
//Here the loop for seeking the coordonate of each petal and add the animate function when I click on it

for (var i = 0 ; i < petale.length; i++) {
  petale[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
  
    var positions =this.getBoundingClientRect();
    var xpetale = positions['x'];
    var ypetale = positions['y'];
    var bottompetale = positions['bottom'];
    var rightpetale = positions['right'];
      
    var distanceX = getDistanceX(xpetale,arriveex);
    var distanceY = getDistanceY(ypetale, arriveey);
//Here, the function to calculate the angle with the Al Kashi formula
    var adjx1 = Math.abs(arriveex-rightpetale);
    var adjy1 = Math.abs(bottompetale-arriveey);
    var adjx2 = Math.abs(xpetale-arriveex);
    var adjy2 = Math.abs(arriveey-ypetale);
    var adjx3 = Math.abs(xpetale-rightpetale);
    var adjy3 = Math.abs(bottompetale-ypetale);
    var side1 = Math.sqrt(adjx1*adjx1+adjy1*adjy1);
    var side2 = Math.sqrt(adjx2*adjx2+adjy2*adjy2);
    var side3 = Math.sqrt(adjx3*adjx3+adjy3*adjy3);
    var angle = Math.acos(((side2*side2)+(side1*side1)-(side3*side3))/(2*side2*side1));
    var deg = (angle*180/Math.PI); 
    this.animate([
        // {transform : 'rotate(75deg)  translateY(-1200px) translateX(150px) scale(1.3)'},
        {transform :`rotate(${deg}deg)`+`translateX(${distanceX}px)` + `translateY(-${distanceY}px)`},
    ],
    {
      duration : 3000,
    }
    )
  })
}
```

The animation doesn't work properly even if I move the rotation (because the order has an importance in CSS ! :p) so I don't know how to make it work for each petal.
I would like that each petal goes in the right place when I click on it so I need a function that can calculate the angle of the rotation and the translation that I need. I hope that it's clear, my english is maybe a little bad...
I can't put my svg because the code is too long even in answer.
Thank you !

Comment: Please add your svg(s) to your question.

Comment: http://oreillymedia.github.io/svg-essentials-examples/ch12/animate_motion_rotate.html

Answer (score 0):

I rather recommend to rebuild your petal group (flower) using transforms.
This way you can simplify the calculation of animated translate and rotate values significantly.

#### Example svg: rotated petals

```js
let petals = document.querySelectorAll('.gPetal');
petals.forEach((petal)=>{
  petal.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    e.currentTarget.style.transform = 'rotate(0)'
  })
})
```

```css
svg {
  width: 30em;
}

text {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  fill: #fff;
  font-size: 6px;
  user-select: none;
  transform: translate(75%, 33%);
  dominant-baseline: central;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.gPetal {
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center;
  cursor:pointer
}

.gPetal[data-rotate="60"] {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.gPetal[data-rotate="120"] {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.gPetal[data-rotate="180"] {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.gPetal[data-rotate="240"] {
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}

.gPetal[data-rotate="300"] {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}
```

```html
<p>Click on a petal to reset rotation</p>
<svg x="0" y="0" width="400" viewBox="0 0 100 100" overflow="visible">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="purple" />
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="red" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <symbol id="petal" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="0.5" />
    <path fill="url(#gradient)" id="circle" d="M50 50 a25 25 0 1 1 50 0 z" />
  </symbol>
    <g class="gPetal gPetal6" data-rotate="300">
      <use href="#petal" />
      <text dy="5%" data-style="font-size:10px">Label 6</text>
    </g>
    <g class="gPetal gPetal5" data-rotate="240">
      <use href="#petal" />
      <text dy="5%" data-style="font-size:10px">Label 5</text>
    </g>
    <g class="gPetal gPetal4" data-rotate="180">
      <use href="#petal" />
      <text dy="5%">Label 4</text>
    </g>
    <g class="gPetal gPetal3" data-rotate="120">
      <use href="#petal" />
      <text dy="5%">Label 3</text>
    </g>
    <g class="gPetal gPetal2" data-rotate="60">
      <use href="#petal" />
      <text dy="5%">Label 2</text>
    </g>
    <g class="gPetal gPetal1" data-rotate="0">
      <use href="#petal" />
      <text dy="5%" data-style="font-size:10px">Label 1</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

[image: petals wireframe]

Each petal is positioned in a square bounding box based on a reused `<symbol>` definition (for the petal's shape and fill).
They are rotated by an angle incremented by 60 degrees for each element.
This way we don't need additional `translate` transformations.
Admittedly some extra work, but it can also help to improve your apps performance by decreasing the svg's filesize.

#### Example: Highlighting/selecting petal

When a petal is selected, the rotation is reset to 0 degrees.
Besides you can add some x/y offsets to shift the element to the right.
The `data-attribute` data-rotate stores the initial rotation and helps to rewind the animation, when a petal gets clicked twice (so becomes deselected).

[image: Selecting petal]

```js
let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
let petals = svg.querySelectorAll(".gPetal");

petals.forEach((petal) => {
  petal.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let current = e.currentTarget;
    let thisStyle = current.style.transform;
    let baseRotation = current.getAttribute("data-rotate");
    let ani = current.animate(
      [
        { transform: "rotate(" + baseRotation + "deg)" },
        { transform: "rotate(0)", color: "#f00", offset: 0.5 },
        { transform: "rotate(0) translate(75%) scale(1.3)" }
      ],
      {
        duration: 500,
        fill: "both"
      }
    );

    //start animation + reset prevously animated
    resetPetals(current, petals);
    if (!current.classList.contains("active")) {
      petal.classList.add("active");
      ani.play();
    } 
    //rewind animation
    else {
      petal.classList.remove("active");
      ani.playbackRate = -1;
      ani.play();
    }
  });
});

function resetPetals(current, petals) {
  petals.forEach((petal, p) => {
      let allAnimations = petal.getAnimations();
      allAnimations.forEach((ani) => {
        ani.playbackRate = 1;
        ani.finish();
        ani.cancel();
      });
    if (petal !== current) {
      petal.classList.remove("active");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
svg {
  width: 30em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

text {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  fill: #fff;
  font-size: 6px;
  user-select: none;
  transform: translate(75%, 33%);
  dominant-baseline: central;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.gPetal {
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center;
  cursor: pointer
}

.gPetal[data-rotate="60"] {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.gPetal[data-rotate="120"] {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.gPetal[data-rotate="180"] {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.gPetal[data-rotate="240"] {
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}

.gPetal[data-rotate="300"] {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

.active {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 400">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="purple" />
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="red" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <symbol id="petal" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none"  />
    <path fill="url(#gradient)" id="circle" d="M50 50 a25 25 0 1 1 50 0 z" />
  </symbol>

  <svg x="0" y="0" width="400" viewBox="0 0 100 100" overflow="visible">
    <g class="gPetal gPetal6" data-rotate="300">
      <use href="#petal" />
      <text dy="5%" data-style="font-size:10px">Label 6</text>
    </g>
    <g class="gPetal gPetal5" data-rotate="240">
      <use href="#petal" />
      <text dy="5%" data-style="font-size:10px">Label 5</text>
    </g>
    <g class="gPetal gPetal4" data-rotate="180">
      <use href="#petal" />
      <text dy="5%">Label 4</text>
    </g>
    <g class="gPetal gPetal3" data-rotate="120">
      <use href="#petal" />
      <text dy="5%">Label 3</text>
    </g>
    <g class="gPetal gPetal2" data-rotate="60">
      <use href="#petal" />
      <text dy="5%">Label 2</text>
    </g>
    <g class="gPetal gPetal1" data-rotate="0">
      <use href="#petal" />
      <text dy="5%" data-style="font-size:10px">Label 1</text>
    </g>
  </svg>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will look at it ! That seems more easier ! :)